# When creating a Matlab MEX function, do I place mexFunction in c++ header file or source file?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am using Matlab's mex function to run some c++ source files. I have several .cpp files that do different conversions. I would like to make one header file that will call these .cpp files. All the examples I see online (so far) only use mex with .cpp files. My question is, where do I use:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
```

In the header? source file? If it is in the header file, do I place it in a class? I'm a bit new to linking files together like this.

Comment: Basically, it doesn't matter. Just put the function implementation in any source file. Classes aren't required.

Comment: Think of `mexFunction` the way you would `main` in a standard program. When matlab invokes the mex file, it calls `mexFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

The example what I provided is from the C or C++ code when I wrote Matlab bindings a year ago. `Mex` is Matlab executable and they are platform dependent, they are not compatible with different platforms and versions.

Add `mex.h` in your source file. Add the C or C++ header file, `mex.h`, containing the MATLAB API function declarations.

---

**Sample code:**

```
/* This header is the must and its the main interface to talk with Matlab*/
#include "mex.h" 
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])     
{
    mexPrintf("howdyyyy!\n"); 
    return;
}
```

You can find the header files of MATLAB, located at `matlab/extern/include`. You can check `matrix.h` file also.

If you use the Matlab editor then you can do like this, The next step is to compile. On the Matlab console, compile `yourfile.cpp` by entering the command

```
$ mex yourfile.cpp
```

The MEX-function is compiled, you can call it from Matlab just like any M-file function, example

**Output.**

```
$ yourfile
howdyyyy!
```

Comment: What if I have a bunch of functions that I want to keep in separate .cpp files with one other .cpp file that decides which to call? I want the user to input the conversion to use in matlab and have the mex code decide which converter to use (Each converter is in their own source file).

Comment: @theNovice are you familiar with [building libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693273/how-do-i-create-a-library)

Comment: In order to use Matlab API it needs a reference to mex.h, you can keep the header file in your header file and include that in your *.cpp files, or other options also ok, till it finds the reference to matlab API.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer Right now I have: convertAtoB.cpp and convertBtoC.cpp where both did what you said. The have their own mexFunction. I want to make a 'convert('A','C',other_inputs)' that calls convertAtoB.cpp and convertBtoC.cpp to get the answer.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer I'm not familiar with building libraries. Should I make functions that do the conversions (without mexFunction), put them in a library, and have one mexxed source file that uses them?

Comment: simple and straightforward way to you is just adding mex.h in both files, and compile it and see what it says

Comment: Only two files, then `mex doBoth.cpp convertAtoB.cpp convertBtoC.cpp` where doBoth.cpp  contains `mexFunction` and `mexFunction` does whatever is needed to call A and B.

Comment: @user4581301, yes I corrected it. I missed to add or in between C or C++.