# Is it possible to hide library code for arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have developed a library for arduino and it is working fine. It consists of two files i.e. .h and .cpp. Is it possible to hide my code or convert it to format like dll so it is unreadable? I m looking to hide my library code. 
Thanks

Comment: Create an *actual* library (shared or static) and [`strip`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/strip.html) debugging symbols? Also considering creating a second header file that could be distributed publicly together with the library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693273/how-do-i-create-a-library)

Comment: @Moia arduino is a bit different and requires distinct steps.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/66578/how-to-prevent-modify-library-of-arduino/66586#66586

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible for Arduino IDE 1.8.6 and above.

You will have to set the precompiled flag in your library to true, and then point to statically compiled library of your code.

Link for library definitions for Arduino.
https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification#libraryproperties-file-format

Link on how to compile a static library.
https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/library.html

Link of Arduino Github discussion regarding the same
https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/4336#issuecomment-444267394