# How to create your own C++ Library and share it with others so that everyone can use it?

Tags: c++, header-files

Everyone knows about the STL , like how it gives us prebuilt containers and functionalities.
Similarly I want to create my own library for the Linked Lists as a learning project, where I want to add the functionalities  :

Able to define what type of list i want (DLL , SLL , Circular LL , Doubly Circular LL)
Insert a node , able to insert at any position
Delete a node , delete any node specified.
And many more .

But the main problem is that I dont know how to create a library and watching the tutorials is not much help.

I am expecting that I will be able to create a library and can include it a program anywhere in the system.
I also want to share these libraries with  others so just like STL others can use the my library.

Any help is  appreciated.
Edit : Please also mention the necessary commands or structure for it .

Comment: Create your library. Create header files to be shared. Share the sources for the implementation (or precompiled artifacts).

Comment: `DLL , SLL` -- These are already provided by `std::list` and `std::forward_list`, respectively.  `Circular LL , Doubly Circular LL` -- These are not provided by the STL containers, so maybe you should focus on these.  Also, please tag one language, either C or C++.

Comment: [How do I create a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693273/how-do-i-create-a-library)

Comment: Posting to a public repository, such as GitHub, is one way to share code. You could also submit your library to a project such as Boost.